# Other program input & manipulation using Python

Tags: python, input

Using python, I am trying to call another program 'mkmod96' to create an Earth model.
When using 'mkmod96' into the konsole the program asks for user input for several parameters until user is finised, at which point the program is cancelled using `Ctrl + D` of `Ctrl+Z`. Looking like this:

```
"mkmod96
 Write creating model96 file for isotropic constant velocity layers, 1-D model
 Enter name of the earth model file
model.d
  Model file is :model.d
 Enter model comment
Iso
  Comment is    :Iso
 Enter 0 for flat earth model
       1 for spherical earth model
0
  Model flat/sph: 0
 Enter Velocity Model, EOF to end:
  H     VP     VS      RHO    QP QS ETAP ETAS FREFP FREFS
 (km) (km/s) (km/s) (gm/cm^3) -- -- ---- ----  (Hz)  (Hz)
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
  10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.
Creating the model file:model.d"
```

I need to automate this process and would like to do it using python.
So far I have a script called 'SWD.py' to call 'mkmod96', at which point I enter in the information manually. (I would also like to be able to automate this part eventually). However when I get to cancelling 'mkmod96', the step of 'Ctrl + D' cancels 'mkmod96' AND my python script. I want to be able to call up more programs to plot etc. the data.
This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
################################
# Step 1: Create an Earth Model
os.system('mkmod96')
################################
# Step 2: Plot the Earth model
os.system('shwmod96 -P -S -VMIN 0 -VMAX 10')
```

So at the moment, I can't get to step 2 in the program. What I think will solve this is some sort of EOF C-shell equivalent? Or set some parameter in the python script that cancels the mkmod96 program?
The problem is that I have to use Ctrl D or Ctrl Z to end mkmod96.

Comment: Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). Not a big pro in this, hence not an answer.